# Faster Keybindings (Universal)

Tags: keyboard, macos, keybindings

How can I universally change the following keybindings to something that is faster?

- Option+Arrow (move 1 word)
- Option+[delete] (delete 1 word)
- Command+c (copy)
- Command+v (paste)
- Command+x (cut)
- Command+z (undo)

Contorting my pinky to press the command key is too slow

OS version: 
MacOS Sierra 10.12.6

I have tried swapping keys. Swapping keys messed up other shortcuts. I have also looked for keymapping software.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  What ways have you already tried?  Please [edit] your question with what you've tried so we don't repeat things that don't work for you.  See [ask] for info.

Comment: In the end, you're **still** attempting to remap macOS keys to Windows keys.

Comment: You're not meant to use your pinky for the command key. Shortcuts such as ⌘C are performed by placing your thumb on ⌘ and forefinger on C. If you still want to remap keys, there are many Q&As on this site regarding software and tools to remap keys on the keyboard. If you're having difficulty remapping keys, clearly describe your problem and the research you've done so far, including attempted solutions with why they didn't work, and give a defined mapping including what you want to map *to* such that it can be answered objectively with a specific answer to solve the problem.

Comment: I never said I wanted to remap a key. (Maybe I misused the word keybinding) That would create new problems with other shortcuts being lost or (if swapped) becoming awkward. As I described above, I just want to change the universal shortcuts. Swapping keys did not solve the problem. I wonder what was the reason to make users use their thumbnails to press common shortcuts.